# Are children a reason to be rejected for a job?

Tags: resume, applications, germany, discrimination, family

After working for 5 years in an industrial environment I want to change to Academia. My CV matches the positions where I applied so far pretty well, but until now I have only received rejections.

I don't know how to handle these rejections, because I'm not used to that. When I wanted to change jobs in the past, I got an invitation for an interview and after that at least one week later I got a contract.

During a short interview by phone, the interviewer asked me if I carefully considered everything regarding such a position, since I have kids. Could it be possible that the reason for rejection is that I have two kids (which I mention in my CV)? Should I delete personal information like this from my CV?

**Edit**

For the ones that are interested in the answers from Academia, I just posted my question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134417/what-could-be-the-reasons-to-be-rejected-as-a-doctoral-candidate-in-germany)

**Small Update**

Got an invitation for an interview :)

Comment: Why do you mention you have kids on your CV?

Comment: For those that are wanting an answer to my question, i took a look online and it doesn't appear to be uncommon to include such information in Germany. I'll add the German tag as maybe my answer is not suitable for working in Germany.

Comment: I see in one of the answer comments you are working on getting a degree. Do the positions require this degree? Also - it's possible they thought that this job + degree study + kids would be too much (rightly or wrongly)

Comment: In the current economy, competition for industry jobs is lower than for academic jobs. You should at least consider other reasons why getting a position is harder than you are used to.

Comment: "During a short interview by phone, the interviewer asked me if I carefully considered everything regarding such a position, since I have kids." Did you consider everything required for the position? I doubt they would reject you for having kids but they might reject you if they aren't satisfied with how you answer this question.

Comment: Since this question is about applying for an academic position, you may also find [academia.se] helpful.

Comment: What Academic experience you have or how long is doing your graduation work passed? I would expect typically too high salary expectations or too little academic experience being the main reasons. Children should only be a problem if you request part-time or of this is a very Junior or a very Senior position :)

Comment: @eckes Besides my job in the industry I work as a lecturer at an university for software architecture and design and that is all the academic experience I have (so not really much) In nearly all job descriptions it is already written how much money you will get in the position, so it is not really possible (I think) to ask for more money, and they can´t know how much I expect when they reject me directly without even an interview. Most times (what I hear) these positions are filled with students directly after their master studies, so their experience shouldn´t be too high as well.

Comment: Yes, if this is a junior position universities prefer home grown candidates, since they are kind of responsible for them. However if you already lectured it sounds like you do have a good connection with academia.

Comment: I concur with @DavidK that it may be worth asking a question on [academia.se]. It is quite likely that there is a completely different problem with what you are trying to do. However, this can only become apparent if you reveal some more details about your CV and the kind of position you are aspiring.

Comment: While you should avoid citing that you have kids by your initiative, you should still be prepared to the **unfair** question "do you have or plan to have children?"

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ > Not only unfair but also illegal in some countries. Be prepared to it is easy: "I'm currently single so I can hardly make any plans". This may be a lie, but who cares? On the other hand I wouldn't be willing to work for a company that disciminates based on that fact...

Comment: At least the German employers I know (granted not academia) actually like parents as they are most often the more stable employees as they depend on the job. (It’s certainly more predictable than newlyweds with no child leave, yet)

Comment: I feel that we don’t know what „such a position“ entails. It cold be a short term grant, unstable funding, politics dependent research fielt, a lab in the antarctic handling dm, a conference marathon around the globe or visiting nightclubs to entertain sponsors (kidding) in all cases the interviewer might want to protect you from accepting the position.

Answer (score 78):

**(It is in dispute if this answer is suitable for Germany)**

*Are children a reason to be rejected for a job?*

Yes.

*Are children a VALID reason to be rejected for a job?*

No.

*How can I prove they rejected me for this invalid reason?*

You cannot.

Remove the personal information from your CV.

You may want to take a close look at your CV to make sure there are no other "red flags" (legitimate or otherwise) that may decrease your chances. Given that somehow the fact you have children has ended up on your CV, and you're having trouble landing the position, your CV probably needs a bit of work.

Comment: *Remove the personal information from your CV* -- this.  People who are looking to fill a position look for a way to eliminate candidates first.

Comment: Remove the personal information from your CV: Bad advice for Germany. This is perfectly legal and expected to be there. Omitting it will raise a red flag and is likely do more harm than good.

Comment: @Hilmar For enough. Do you have advice on how to proceed here?

Comment: @Hilmar I did ask the OP why they included it, but they never bothered to get back to me.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie As I wanted to answer your comment on my question, you already commented again, with what is absolutely correct, that it is not uncommon and expected in a german CV. Given that you answered your question already, I thought it is not required to give a redundant answer. Sorry.

Comment: @SMa Hearing it from you is a lot more meaningful than what I can find online. In any case, I'm really not sure how to proceed. If it was an illegitimate reasons, I'm guessing it would be illegal to ask...?

Comment: This is a perfect answer for Germany, please remove the warning. I do not know which Germany Hilmar is talking about but it cannot be the same as my country. I neither know anybody who would put information about his family life on a job application, not did I ever recieve an application containing it. People may include hobbies or similar for the personal touch, but never anything about children. Big companies even have processes to remove personal information to avoid legal trouble.

Comment: @Chris That sounds believable. Could this depend on the industry or something? I've amended my answer.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: I am not aware of any such industry, even in childcare it doesn't matter, because most employees are young women without own children. I did a quick Google research about "Kinder im Lebenslauf" (children in CV) and all websites agree that in most cases that's a risk and only in very specific cases you might want to mention it. But definitely is nowhere near expected.

Comment: @Gregory Currie It might also be a generational difference. I know my parents were taught to include family status and the like on their CV, but that started to fade when I was in high school and nowadays almost nobody does it anymore and even hobbies are only a thing for students who don't have much else to get their CV up to one full page. I'd say your answer is right for Germany, too.

Comment: How can an answer that is not for Germany be so upvoted?

Comment: @guest It is only in dispute if it is suitable for Germany. The answer was made before the tag of Germany was added. In addition, the answer is not just for the OP, but others that may have the same question.

Comment: Tbh, those are muddy waters. It is not legal to be rejected solely on that basis, much less for public employment. However, I have also seen young women (25-35) discriminated against if they did not have children already. This is due to a typical maternity leave of at least a year. Indicating that you already have children helps. Both my wife an myself have it on our CVs, and it did not seem to hinder us from finding new jobs. I even got rejected of a job at a large company for not showing enough human side!

Answer (score 13):

As you didnt put a location I will bring in my German perspective:

Here, it is common to get only yearly contracts when working in academia(even for doctoral degree roles) and thus having an unstable income. Another point is you will need to work long hours in order to finish your degree, which might be a problem when you have to take care of your children. I think those are the main reason why the questions regarding your children are coming up. From an employer perspective, it can be seen as a problem or an obstacle.

If you are okay with having to work long hours, having a lower income and an unstable job, then leave the information about your children out of your CV.

You can still talk about it during an interview and highlight your ability to handle family **and** working long hours.

Comment: For Germany, do you know the legality of rejecting someone based on having children? I couldn't find a direct reference for protections for parents, but if the company would have accepted a *father* but not a mother, that would be considered sex discrimination.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the stuff regarding money and working hours, but after long talks with my wife, we came to the conclusion that we could handle that for the time until I hopefully would obtain the degree.

Comment: @DavidK I cant find a reference just now but I am pretty sure this would be illegal. however such claims can be hard to prove **IMHO**

Comment: @SMa I thought most academia job require PhD degree and you are working toward a degree. Why do you think you can get an academic job without PhD? Are you looking for TA/RA job? Most TA/RAs are offered to graduate students. If you are a PhD student, you should be already a TA/RA. If you are working toward a master degree, the chance of getting academic job is slim.

Comment: @scaaahu Probably my post was not completely clear. At the moment I have a master degree and working in a software company in Germany. Now I am applying for jobs as a research assistant which also offer the possibility to obtain a PhD in order to get a job in academia at an university

Comment: @SMa "research assistant which also offer the possibility to obtain a PhD" is legalese for "paid PhD position". The focus of your application needs to be on the PhD and not on becoming a research assistant. I hope you know this.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I know that, but thank you. I always point out in my application that one of my main motivations is to obtain the PhD.

Comment: @SMa I suspect that they are worried whether you can sustain the commitment for the necessary three to five years while having dependents (and being used to a good payment in the industry). You should try to address this worry preemptively.

Comment: @SMa I'm not so familiar with the academic environment in Germany, but are you applying directly to a *job*, which you think will be a good gateway to the PhD program, or are you applying/have you applied to the PhD program and are now looking for a research job as a part of that? My confusion is because in the U.S. applying for an RA type of job without already being in the PhD program is unusual and a difficult route to follow.

Comment: @Upper_Case Germany has lots of what is called ustructured PhD programs. For these it is quite common to apply to the RA position and if you get the job you are more or less automatically accepted into the PhD program - in practice, you apply to both with the one application for the RA job.

Comment: @Sumyrda That makes the question a lot clearer, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I can only speak from personal experience, but most likely your children are not the reason: in Germany, it can be incredibly difficult to get into academia.

Our university has a daycare for children and if you can’t get a spot there and no one from your family can take care of your children while you are at work, you are allowed to take the children to work or pay a babysitter (which will partly be paid by the university).

I‘ve heard many times that it is difficult to get a job in academia, especially if they don’t know you and/or you didn’t study there. When I considered dropping out of academia and taking another job, a lot of people (from other universities as well) told me to reconsider, because it would be very hard for me to get back into an academic position after working in the industry. Even if your CV looks good and your experience is valuable, it is very likely that the children are not the reason, they just preferred someone they knew, someone who studied there or was recommended to them.

Comment: "Even if your CV looks good and your experience is valuable, it is very likely that the children are not the reason, they just preferred someone they knew, someone who studied there or was recommended to them" You should ask in academia.stackexchange.com too, but imho @Snailshell is correct in his assumption.

Comment: I also think that more than your children, Snailshell is pointing to the real issue. Academia, in Germany, and to my experience, has a lot of networking. And for many employment, recommendation, or previous contacts is a must. Coming from the industry is much harder.